# How to enable opentracing on TCP ports

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaeger, opentracing, jaeger-client-go

So, I am trying to trace logs of my spring boot application with jaeger so below are the steps that i did my application and jaeger configuration. My issue is its works fine when I'm enabling UDP on Jaeger,but i need is enable TCP on here.

It's Working fine as per below below UDP configuration,
***Jager docker service***

```
docker run -d -e COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HTTP_PORT=9411 -p 5775:5775/udp -p 6831:6831/udp -p 6832:6832/udp -p 5778:5778 -p 16686:16686 -p 14268:14268 -p 9411:9411 jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
```

***YML as per below***

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service-v11
opentracing:
  jaeger:
    service-name: service-v11
    enable: true
    udp-sender:
      host:  172.15.15.15
  sampler:
    type: const
    param: 1
server:
  port: 8090
```

But when i use  below configuration jaeger service its up adn running but  not hit the tracing request ,

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    ports:
      - 4318:4318
      - 16686:16686
    environment:
      - COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Opentracing is deprecated. To instrument using OpenTelemetry follow this tutorial: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/getting-started/ this will automatically instrument the Spring Boot application. If you have questions, we can help on the Slack community for the CNCF in both #opentelemetry and #jaeger channels!